# UICollectionView alignment of cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView with 2 different types of UICollectionViewCells.  There is a tab that prompts the showing of each type of cell and only one type of cell can be visible at a time.

For some reason, 1 type of cell aligns left in the UICollectionView, but the other cell horizontally aligns in the center.  I'd like both types of cells to align left.

Edge insets are:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The cells will layout differently depending on their size, so you need to use different insets for each of your cell types. I think it should be doable like this:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:section];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MyClass1 class]]){
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10,10,10);
    }else{
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,10,10,10);
}
```

Substitute your correct class name for MyClass1 and experiment with the edge insets until you get the behavior you want.

Comment: Thanks, it was a dumb mistake. I didn't realize it but the cell that was centered was too wide to have more than one cell in the row.  I have since reduced the size of the cell and resolved the problem.